# MQTT publish message to selected clients

Tags: python, mqtt

I am working on MQTT and using python paho-mqtt https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt

I am unable to understand how can I publish msg to a specific client or list of clients?

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't know MQTT particularly, but usually with message queue systems you don't publish to a client, you publish messages with a particular key and clients decide whether or not they subscribe to that key.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly possible with strict MQTT, although some brokers may offer that functionality, or you can construct your application so that the topic design works to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do agree that in some cases it would be useful to send a message to a particular client (or list of clients) that's simply not how the publish/subscribe messaging paradigm works. [Read more on the publish-subscribe pattern on Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) If all your system needs to do is send messages to unique clients, then I would perhaps suggest thinking of a different architecture for the system you are designing. That being said, you can leverage off pub/sub to achieve what you want using a clever topic design architecture.

For example, let's assume all clients are part of a group (list), you could think of the following topic design:

Unique per client: *P2P/< client-name >*

List/Group subscription: *LIST/< list-name >*

For example, *P2P/user12345* and *LIST/QA* where only user12345 subscribes to *P2P/user12345* but all users of the QA group subscribe to *LIST/QA*.

It would be the client's responsibility to ensure that it is subscribed to its own topic(s) (or if your broker allows it, you could also add the topics administratively to non-clean clients).

With this design, a publisher would be able to send a message to a specific user or all members of a defined group (list).